# How to make django serve static files in development?

Tags: python, django, django-staticfiles

For some reason my django project doesn't see my static files, giving me 404 error, like so:

**"GET /static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 404 1757**

I do everything in accordance with the official guide. Here is my project structrure:

```
PMpro:
    -PMpro (main project)
    -users (app)
    -tasks (another app)
    -static
        --js
        --css
        --etc...
    -templates
        --template files...
    -manage.py
```

**My settings.py file:**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIR = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
```

**urls.py file:**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='index.html'))
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

**In my .html file I's collecting static files and linking to corresponding css/js file like so:**

```
    {% load static %}

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/organicfoodicons.css' %}" />
```

I'm pretty sure I do everything in accordance with the official django guide, and yet my project doesn't see/serve my static files.

I have already went through a number of similar problems people were posting here, and I have everything im my code exactly as it was advised, but the problem is still there.

**Folks, any suggestions?**

Comment: Added to `INSTALLED_APPS`? `DEBUG` set to `True`?

Comment: @KlausD. Yes, Users, Tasks apps and 'django.contrib.staticfiles', are added to INSTALLED_APPS and DEBUG is set to TRUE.

Comment: The setting name is `STATICFILES_DIRS`. You are missing the *S*.

Comment: Note that you are using `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),` in `STATICFILES_DIRS` (locations that static files are collected from) and `STATIC_ROOT` (the place that static files are copied to). You should change `STATIC_ROOT` to something else. It doesn't even need to be in your `PMpro` directory, since it isn't usually checked in.

Comment: @Alasdair, omg. Seriously? Thanks mate, there is 'S missing indeed. It works now